# countdown with date is showing extra time

Tags: flutter, dart

showing timer based on date and time. Extra hours are added in the timer. If the expected remaining time is 2 hours it shows 23 days. The calcucation isn't correct I guess
Here is the code and also pasted console log data beside every print statement.
Even some of the code doesn't execute(Check `setState`)

```
auctionTimer({final endingTime, String postId, String ownerId}) {
  const duration = const Duration(seconds: 1);
  print(endingTime); //2021-08-01 02:51:04.038(console log)in timestamp(Timestamp(seconds=1627766464, nanoseconds=38000000))
  final eventTime = DateTime.parse("$endingTime");
  DateTime d = DateTime.now().toUtc();
  print(d); //2021-08-02 14:00:23.633197Z(console log)
  int timeDiff = eventTime.difference(d).inSeconds;
  print(timeDiff); //-146359(console log)
  
  Timer timer = Timer.periodic(duration, (Timer t) {
    if (timeDiff > 0) {
//these lines of code(setState) doesn't  execute. I confirmed with print statements.
      setState(() {
        if (eventTime != d) {
          timeDiff = timeDiff - 1;
          return print('not ended'); //doesn't show up in log
        } else {
          return print('Times up!'); // doesn't show in log

        }
      });
    }
  });

  days = timeDiff ~/ (24 * 60 * 60) % 24;
  hours = timeDiff ~/ (60 * 60) % 24;
  minutes = (timeDiff ~/ 60) % 60;
  seconds = timeDiff % 60;
  Duration remainingTime;
  return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      LabelText(label: 'DAYS', value: days.toString().padLeft(2, '0')),
      LabelText(label: 'HRS', value: hours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')),
      LabelText(label: 'MIN', value: minutes.toString().padLeft(2, '0')),
      LabelText(label: 'SEC', value: seconds.toString().padLeft(2, '0')),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Timer shows extra time like 23 days. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @WardSuleiman extra hours are added in the timer. If the expected remaining  time is 2 hours it shows 23 days